# how to tell mesos frameworks which launched by different commands/parameters

Tags: apache-spark, mesos, marathon

I am building metrics collector to collect the running status about all the Spark Jobs running on it. The mesos API http://masterip/frameworks return a lot of details about all the frameworks and then I run http://slaveip/slave(1)/monitor/statistics to get each frameworks detail info from each slave, then correlate them.

This works fine for most of the jobs, but I have some jobs which behave different according to different parameters when submitting. They are shown as same framework name in Mesos GUI and I can not tell each other.

Is there a way to get the detail full commands which launches the job? Or any other idea about how to tell them?

[You can find there are multiple instances with same framework name. As they are different spark job instances.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9bM3.png)

When I connect to Mesos slave, the monitor/statistics doesn't show the full command with all the parameters, so I can not tell which framework correlate to which Spark job instance.

```
  {
    "executor_id": "0",
    "executor_name": "Command Executor (Task: 0) (Command: sh -c ' 
\"/usr/local...')",
    "framework_id": "06ba8de8-7fc3-422d-9ee3-17dd9ddcb2ca-3157",
    "source": "0",
    "statistics": {
      "cpus_limit": 2.1,
      "cpus_system_time_secs": 848.689999999,
      "cpus_user_time_secs": 5128.78,
      "mem_limit_bytes": 4757389312,
      "mem_rss_bytes": 2243149824,
      "timestamp": 1522858776.20098
    }
  },
```

Thanks

Comment: Martin you may try asking on the Apache Mesos slack channel. DC/OS provides a simple way to install and manage Mesos and Spark - along with a few 100 other packages. It ships also as open source and includes a built in metrics API. You can check it out at dcos.io.

Comment: Can you post a sample output/screenshot you have and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @janisz! I've uploaded the snapshot which shows 3 different spark job instances which all named as "hmrMonitor", from the GUI it is hard to tell them as they are launched by spark with different parameters. When I visit the http://mesos-slave:5051/slave(1)/monitor/statistics, it doesn't show the full command, so I can not tell them.

Comment: @Corbin, thanks for your suggestion, however deploying Dcos is a big change to us, we will do that future release, but not current phase.

Comment: So you need to match them by taskId and executorId with data from spark

Comment: Thanks @janisz! The CPU data I collected back looks like quite promising. But I have some doubt about the spark driver memory. I configured the driver memory is 4G in the spark conf, but looks like in Mesos and Spark UI it shows only around 1G. Is this info correct? (BTW: we are using Marathon as scheduler and it only configured 0.1 CPU and 64M memory as the initial value.

Comment: As same logic in Diamond collector, I just take mem limit bytes as the allocated mem and mem rss bytes as the used memory. Will that be fine? Thanks!